# infinite loop in divide part in mergeSort

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I'm trying to implement merge_sort(recursive)in c,but the function myMergesort seems to continue to do the divide part and to never enter the merge part

I'm using as pseudocode:

```
mergeSort (array A, index i, index f, array X)
/* Order A[i..f − 1] using X as auxiliary array */
if more than 1 element then
    m ← (i + f)/2 
    mergeSort(A, i, m, X)
    mergeSort(A, m, f, X) 
    merge(A, i, m, f, X)
```

And my code is:

```
void myMergesort(int a[], int i ,int f,int x[]){
    nloop++;//global variable to count number of iterations
//if I don't do this infinite loop and segmentation fault
    if(nloop>20){
        printf("infinite loop :(\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(f>1){
        printArr(a,i,f-1);//prints elements of arr a from i to f-1
        int m = (f+i)/2;
        printf("myMergesort(a,%d,%d,x)\n",i,m);
        myMergesort(a,i,m,x);
        printf("myMergesort(a,%d,%d,x)\n",m,f);
        myMergesort(a,m,f,x);
        merge(a,i,m,f,x);
    }
    else printf("this part of the array already ordered\n");

}
```

calling mergeSort on array that contains 5 1 the output is:

```
myMergesor(a,0,2,x)
5 1 
myMergesor(a,0,1,x)
this part of the array already ordered
myMergesor(a,1,2,x)
1 
myMergesor(a,1,1,x)
this part of the array already ordered
myMergesor(a,1,2,x)
1 
myMergesor(a,1,1,x)
this part of the array already ordered
myMergesor(a,1,2,x)
1 
myMergesor(a,1,1,x)
this part of the array already ordered
myMergesor(a,1,2,x)
1 
myMergesor(a,1,1,x)
this part of the array already ordered
myMergesor(a,1,2,x)
1 
myMergesor(a,1,1,x)
this part of the array already ordered
myMergesor(a,1,2,x)
1 
myMergesor(a,1,1,x)
this part of the array already ordered
myMergesor(a,1,2,x)
1 
myMergesor(a,1,1,x)
infinite loop :(
```

I'm convinced that the error is in myMergesort function since I've checked that it never enters the merge part;
but just in case..,
I'm calling it in main like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //input of integers from command line
    int sequenza[argc-1];
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        sequenza[i-1]=atoi(argv[i]);
    }
    algoMergesort(sequenza,argc-1);
    //print result 
    printArr(sequenza,0,argc-2);
}

void algoMergesort(int a[], int n){
    int x[n];
    printf("myMergesor(a,0,%d,x)\n",n);
    myMergesort(a,0,n,x);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition of the `if` statement is not correct (`f>1`).

It should check whether the subarray running from `i` to `f` (`f` excluded) contains more than one element. But `f` is not giving you that size, it should be `f-i`, so change the `if` to:

```
if (f-i>1) {
```